# How to dynamically normalize nested json structure in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Example: Based on this (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_nested_and_repeated_json_data)
We have got a use case where we have to load the header part, id, firstname, lastname, dob into separate table and address into separate table.

I am aware of this in can be done.

- programmatic manner like json.normalize - however how do we achieve this in BigQuery?
- using record data type in bigquery

However, our requirement is to normalize it to separate tables and also have loosely type data type of columns level as all STRING (as in a date field in json is not date when we normalize, it has to be STRING).

Comment: Can you add some sample data so we can properly answer your question? From what I read you should be using Json_Value function to parse the data into your tables, such as JSON_VALUE(header.id). By normalization you mean unnesting the JSON ?

Comment: Venkatesh, to elaborate further do you mean, how to 1) identify number of nested objects 2) normalize it (unnest) 3) load in table each per normalized structure. @ZiyaMertKarakas fyi, the link has example nested structure - there id, firstname, lastname, dob into separate table and address goes in separate table

Comment: I think this link will help your use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70918897/flatten-json-string-in-bigquery?rq=2

Comment: use json_value and unnest. In case of arrays inside arrays, use struct.